# Will upgrading to a later release improve laptop hardware support?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, upgrade, 16.04, laptop

I'm currently running 14.04 on my dual boot ASUS ROG 752 VL laptop. To my disappointment, I haven't been able to find drivers for the trackpad; the laptop doesn't sleep when I'd expect it to; hotkey functionality is unavailable; etc.

My question is whether upgrading to a more recent release should be expected to solve any of this.

Comment: It is very easy to check from a LiveUSB.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried the bootable USB (16.04), but got no further than a blank desktop

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade the kernel to version 4.4 without upgrading the release.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

and reboot.

This will install kernel from Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The support was much better: touchpad and volume function keys worked